# Unity, GUI, C# - Argument is out of range

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

I started creating Inventory System and i have one annoying error.

I have 3 scripts

- Item, for create item "template"
- ItemsDatabase, for storing all items
- Inventory, for storing information about items in backpack.

When i hit play button, everything is working fine, but also i have hundreds of errors:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
>   Parameter name: index
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Item].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
>   Inventory.OnGUI () (at Assets/Inventory.cs:23)

Unity says, it's the problem with "Inventory", so there's script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour {

public List<Item> inventory = new List<Item>();
private ItemsDatabase database;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    database = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Item Database").GetComponent<ItemsDatabase>();
    inventory.Add(database.items[0]);
    inventory.Add(database.items[1]);

}

void OnGUI()
{
    for (int i = 0; 1 < inventory.Count; i++)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, i * 30, 200, 50), inventory[i].itemName); (THERE'S THE ERROR!)
    }
}
```

Every tip for solving the problem is welcome

Comment: You probably should test `i < inventory.Count` instead of `1 < inventory.Count`.

Comment: Och my god, that's so stupid mistake!
Thank you so much! :)